# Clearing commit message in Eclipse (while using Mylyn)

Tags: eclipse, mylyn

No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get Mylyn to **stop** inserting a commit message based on a Task even though that task is no longer active and closed. I've tried restarting the app, I've tried activating and inactivating tasks (which seems to simply change the commit message, although this is not consistent).

Switching to different perspectives also does not resolve the problem.

There must be some switch somewhere that I am neglecting to turn off. Please help me fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:** Mylyn automatically creates meaningful commit messages based on the tasks you've worked on.  To disable them see the **Disabling** section below.

**Disabling:** To disable Mylyn's commit messages go to `Preferences -> Tasks -> Team` and remove all content from the `Commit Comment Template`.

**Details:** Mylyn commit messages are automatically generated by using your context to determine which tasks where active when you changed the set of files you are about to commit.  Thus, if you had the task *implement the submit button* active when you changed the file `Submit.java` then when you commit `Submit.java` the commit message will automatically be filled in with *implement the submit button* and a link to that task.  Here's an example of a filled in commit message for the task *improve upon associations prototype*:

[image: Commit Message]

Many people find this more convenient than having to copy and paste from your task or type in a commit message yourself.  Additionally, there are several advantages to having the commit message filled in by Mylyn, such as having traceability back to the task and having correct annotations.  Here's an example of the traceability that having Mylyn-generated commit messages allows.  You can see that the code annotations have links directly back to the tasks.

[image: Code Annotations]

See this article for further details and advantages: [Mastering Change-Sets](http://tasktop.com/blog/mylyn/mastering-eclipse-change-sets)

David Shepherd, Tasktop Technologies 
 http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd

Comment: Okay, just to make sure I have this right -- if I edit and commit a file while a Task is active, that file will **always** have that commit message applied, I guess until I commit it with another message or something? I love that Mylyn does this for me when the Task is **active**, but I'd like it to stop as soon as the task has been deactivated and I'm no longer in the context.

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it. Mylyn will remember that you've changed file X while task Y was active and always add the task as part of the commit message.  If you change file X during task Y *and* task Z then it will have both tasks in the commit message.  As soon as you commit this change the messages will be reset for this file.  Unfortunately, Mylyn does this whether you have a task active during commit or not.  So, you can either have this feature on all the time or off all the time, but it is not dependent on a task being active.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Preferences -> Tasks -> Team` : clear the `Commit Comment Template`